# In a regular top space, is it true that for every $x \in X$ and closed set $C \subseteq X$, $\exists$ open nbh of x $G$ s.t $\overline{G}\subset C^C$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, semicontinuous-functions

As part of a bigger problem the following argument is applied:

Let $X$ be a regular topological space I is a lower semicontinuous function $X \rightarrow [0,+\infty]$. (...)

Let $x \in X$ be fixed and let $c<I(x)$. By definition of lower semicontinuity the set  $C=\{I \le c\}$ is closed One can separate $x$ from $C=\{I \le c\}$. Thus there exists an open set $G$ containing $x$ such that $\overline{G}\subset \{I >c \}$.

I am having trouble with the last sentence. As far as I know, as stated in my notes:a topological space is regular if points and closed sets can be separated by disjoint open neighborhoods.
Therefore I would say that there exists disjoint open sets $G$ and  $H$, such that $x\in G$, $C \subseteq H$. But in the problem I am reading they seem to use some property or equivalence. It looks like that regularity implies or is equivalent to  :

"for every $x \in X$ and closed set $C \subseteq X$ $\exists$ open $G$ with   $x\in G$ s.t $\overline{G}\subset C^C$"

**Is this an alternative definition or property ? Or just an implication? I tried proving it but I am not getting anything meaningful. Can someone help me prove it?**

Answer (score 1):

A well-known alternative characterization of regularity is this:

For each $x \in X$ and each open $U \subset X$ such that $x \in U$ there exists an open $V \subset X$ such that $x \in V$ and $\overline V  \subset U$.

This is easy to prove and can be found in any textbook on general topology.

It is precisely that what you want to use.